Struggling with proof of Theorem 2.24 in Shafarevich's book (finiteness of certain regular map)
I have difficulties to follow the proof of Theorem 2.24 in Shafarevich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry 1. There is another question on the same proof here at MSE, but I am struggling for different reasons. So this is not a duplicate. I am copying the statement and proof from the other question:

Theorem 2.24. A regular map $\phi: X \to Y$ from an irreducible nonsingular projective curve $X$ is finite (Section 5.3, Chapter 1) if $Y = \phi(X)$ is a variety with $\dim Y > 0$.
Proof.  Write $V$ for an affine neighbourhood of a point $y \in Y$, and $B = k[V]$. We view $k(Y)$ as a subfield of $k(X)$ under the inclusion $\phi^*$. In particular, $B \subset k(X)$; let $A$ be the integral closure of $B$ in $k(X)$. In the proof of the existence of the normalisation of an algebraic variety, we proved that $A$ is a finite $B$-module, and hence $A = k[U]$, where $U$ is an affine normal curve. Since $U$ is birational to $X$, by Theorem 2.16, Corollary 2.6, we can assume that $U$ is an open subset of $X$. Let us prove that $U = \phi^{−1}(V)$. This will guarantee the finiteness of $\phi$.
Suppose that for some point $y_0 \in V$ there is a point $x_0 \notin U$ with $\phi(x_0) = y_0$. Consider a function $f$ such that $f \notin \mathcal{O}_{x_0}$ but $f \in \mathcal{O}_{x_i}$ for all $x_i \in U$ with $\phi(x_i) = y_0$
and $x_i \neq x_0$. Such a function can easily be constructed by putting $x_0$ and $x_i$ in one affine open set. If $f$ has poles at points $x' \in U$, then $\phi(x') = y' \neq y_0$, and hence we can find a function $h \in B$ such that $h(y_0) \neq 0$ and $f h \in \mathcal{O}_{x'}$, that is, $f h \in A$; for this, we need only take a sufficiently high power of a function that vanishes at $y$.
Then $f_1 = f h$ is integral over $B$, that is $$f_1^n + b_1f_1^{n−1} + \cdots + b_n = 0$$ with $b_i \in B$, so that $f_1 = −b_1 - b_2/f_1 - \cdots - b_n/f_1^{n−1}$. Since $f_1 \neq \mathcal{O}_{x_0}$, we get $f_1^{−1} \in m_{x_0}$. Hence the final equality is a contradiction: the right-hand side is regular at $x_0$, but the left-hand side is not. The theorem is proved.


First of all, the theorem is explicitly stated for projective curves, but I don't see this precondition being used anywhere in the proof. The statement seems false for non-projective curves, as e.g. the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb{A}^1$, $x \mapsto x^2$ is surjective (over $\mathbb{C}$ say) but not finite. Does anyone see where being projective is used in the proof?
I also don't understand why $U$ can be regarded as an open subset of $X$. Since $k[U]$ is defined as the integral closure of $k[V]$ in $k(X)$, I see that $U$ is birational to $X$. But the cited Corollary 2.16 requires a birational regular map $U \to X$. Where does this map come from?
Apart from understanding this proof, I would also be glad to see alternative proofs of the same statement which come with a little bit more details. Thank you in advance!

You're correct that we need projectivity for this proof to work. Your example of $\Bbb A^1\setminus \{1\} \to \Bbb A^1$ by $x\mapsto x^2$ is exactly the sort of counterexample which will show the need for projectivity in this proof: it's not finite - instead, it's a composition of an open immersion and a finite map, and this composition is not finite. (By Zariski's main theorem, this is the only sort of counterexample you can have.)
Stepping through the proof with your counterexample in hand, we start with $X=\Bbb A^1\setminus\{1\}$ and $Y=\Bbb A^1$, so that on the level of coordinate rings our map is the natural inclusion $k[t^2]\to k[t]_{t-1}$. Certainly $k(Y)=k(t^2)$ can be viewed as a subfield of $k(t)$, so the first sentence of the proof is fine. Taking $V=Y$ with coordinate algebra $B=k[t^2]$, the integral closure $A$ of $k[t^2]\subset k(t)$ is $k[t]$, so $U=\Bbb A^1$ which is birational to $\Bbb A^1\setminus \{1\}$ but the rational map $\Bbb A^1\dashrightarrow \Bbb A^1\setminus \{1\}$ specified by the equality of function fields does not extend to a regular map, let alone an open immersion which would let us view $U$ as an open subset of $X$.
In fact, this is the place where we need projectivity: if $U$ is a normal curve and $Y$ is any projective variety, then any rational map $U\dashrightarrow Y$ extends to an honest morphism $U\to Y$. (This also answers your question "where does $U\to Y$ come from?") This result often goes by "the curve-to-projective extension theorem" - there are varying levels of sophistication for the proof, but the basic idea is that if $u\in U$ is a point where our map is not defined, we can write our map locally near $u$ as $[a_0z^{b_0}:\cdots:a_nz^{b_n}]$ where $a_i$ are units in the local ring at $u$ and $z$ is a uniformizer for the local ring at $u$ (which is a DVR by the fact the curve is regular and one-dimensional). Then we simply multiply our map by $z^{-\min(b_i)}$ so that all of the coordinates have non-negative valuation and at least one coordinate has zero valuation, and we see our map extends across $u$. (Pardon me for not citing the corresponding result in Shafarevich, but I have not used his text much and my copy is not with me at present.)

Another perspective on this proof can be found here on MSE - it relies on some higher-powered theorems, notably quasifinite + proper = finite.
